# Using OpenACC to set the value of a variable in device memory

Tags: c++, cuda, openacc, pgi

Why does the following code not allow me to set `var` to `10` via the function `intfun`?

```
#include <iostream>

void intfun(int * variable){
    #pragma acc parallel deviceptr(variable) num_gangs(1) num_workers(1)
    {
        *variable = 10;
    }
}

int main(){
    int var;

    #pragma acc enter data create(var)
    #pragma acc host_data use_device(var)
    {
        intfun(&var);
    }
    #pragma acc exit data copyout(var)

    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation:

```
pgcpp -acc main.cpp
```

Execution:

```
PGCC-S-0155-Compiler failed to translate accelerator region (see -Minfo messages): Unknown variable reference (main.cpp: 5)
PGCC/x86 Linux 14.9-0: compilation completed with severe errors
```

How can I get `intfun` to set the value of the parameter `int var` on the device?

Comment: Take away all the fancy OpenACC pragmas and ask yourself the question "how could `intfun` modify an argument passed by *value* at the caller's scope". Hopefully you will arrive at the answer that it cannot. No compiler magic and pragmas can change that....

Comment: Indeed, please see my edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given the compiler enough information to scope the usage of `*variable` within `intfun`.

The following seems to work fine:

```
$ cat main7.cpp
#include <iostream>

void intfun(int * variable){
    #pragma acc parallel copy(variable[:1])
    {
        *variable = 10;
    }
}

int main(){
    int var;

        intfun(&var);

    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}
$ pgcpp -acc -Minfo main7.cpp
intfun(int *):
      5, Generating copy(variable[:1])
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
$ ./a.out
10
$
```

where I have `copy(variable[:1])`, `copyout(variable[:1])` would work as well, for this particular example.

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003954/how-is-value-being-copied-in-in-openacc