# How is variable in device memory used by external function?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, openacc, pgi

In this code:

```
#include <iostream>

void intfun(int * variable, int value){
    #pragma acc parallel present(variable[:1]) num_gangs(1) num_workers(1)
    {
        *variable = value;
    }
}

int main(){
    int var, value = 29;

    #pragma acc enter data create(var) copyin(value)
        intfun(&var,value);
    #pragma acc exit data copyout(var) delete(value)

    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}
```

How is `int value` recognized to be on device memory in `intfun`? If I replace `present(variable[:1])` by `present(variable[:1],value)` in the `intfun` pragma, I get the following runtime error:

```
FATAL ERROR: data in PRESENT clause was not found on device 1: name=_43144_33_value
 file:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/14.9/include/CC/iostream intfun__FPii line:5
Present table dump for device[1]: NVIDIA Tesla GPU 1, compute capability 3.5
host:0x7fffc11faa28 device:0x2303f20200 size:4 presentcount:1 line:14 name:_43152_14_value
host:0x7fffc11faa34 device:0x2303f20000 size:4 presentcount:2 line:14 name:_43152_9_var
```

I don't understand why specifying that `value` is `present` leads to the failure above. I checked with NVVP that `value` is only copied once in the `enter data` directive, i.e. it is not copied again in the `parallel` directive in `intfun`. How does OpenACC work its magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting confused again by your own syntax and over what was pointed out to you already.

`value` in `intfun` is not the same as `value` that you did `copyin(value)` in `main`.  The function call passes `value` by value, meaning it makes a *copy* of it.  Therefore adding it to a `present()` clause makes no sense because it is *not present* on the device.  The compiler must copy it in. (And when you don't mention it at all, the compiler automatically recognizes that it is needed and copies it in for you.)

The item that *is present* on the device is the `main`-scope variable `value`, which is *not used* by `intfun`.  Giving all your variables the same name is probably not helping you understand this.

To demonstrate this, let's pass `value` *by reference* instead of *by value*:

```
$ cat main8.cpp
#include <iostream>

void intfun(int * variable, int &value){
    #pragma acc parallel present(variable[:1],value) num_gangs(1) num_workers(1)
    {
        *variable = value;
    }
}

int main(){
    int var, value = 29;

    #pragma acc enter data create(var) copyin(value)
        intfun(&var,value);
    #pragma acc exit data copyout(var) delete(value)

    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}
[user2@dc12 misc]$ pgcpp -acc -Minfo main8.cpp
intfun(int *, int &):
      5, Generating present(variable[:1])
         Generating present(value[:])
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
main:
     14, Generating enter data copyin(value)
         Generating enter data create(var)
     17, Generating exit data delete(value)
         Generating exit data copyout(var)
$ ./a.out
29
$
```

Now the main-scope variable `value` is on the device, the compiler knows it, it will be used by `intfun` directly, and adding it to the `present` clause is legal and functional.

Comment: Then I don't understand why in my origin example, `value` isn't copied to the device if I omit it the `copyin(value)` and `delete(value)` in the pragmas in `main`. Where does the device retrieve the value of 29 from? This is stored in host memory and must therefore be copied to device memory at some point right?

Comment: I've already stated in my answer that if you omit any mention of `value` the compiler automatically recognizes that `value` is required by the kernel and it will automatically generate the needed copy for it.  It's only when you specify `present` thefore overriding this behavior, that things break.  If you have a new question, i.e. something else that you don't understand, that is based on different code than what is shown in your question, you might pose a new question.  The `copyin(value)` in `main` is irrelevant to your original code, and your original code works just fine without it.

Comment: I have verified with NVVP that omitting an explicit `copyin` of `value` in `main` leads to no host to device data transfer. I am therefore puzzled as to where the device gets the value of `value` from.

Comment: It can be passed as a kernel parameter.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me figure out some stuff. I wanted to mention that when you say "what was pointed out to you already", it applies to only one of the many people who might benefit from what you've written.